# How can I sidestep no-use-before-define for the variable definition let foo = foo || [];?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, eslint

Using eslint, I'd like to hang on to the rule `no-use-before-define` without it affecting lines like this:

```
let foo = foo || [];
```

Is that even possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

I tried adding `'no-use-before-define': [2, {'variables': false}]`, to my eslintrc, but it had no effect.

Comment: where do you get `foo` without having it?

Comment: Seems like a wrong way. Why do you **declare** a variable and assign it to itself as an initial default value? If you have that variable already declared, why do you use `let` here?

Comment: It's part of the tracking code for Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the global scope (as I believe is the case with Google Analytics) you can do the assignment through the `window` object.

```
window.foo = window.foo || [];
```